# Why this JavaScript property returns empty string, while JavaScript function works fine?

Tags: javascript, properties, closures, getter-setter

Consider this simple JavaScript module pattern:

```
var human = (function () {
    var _name = '';
    return {
        name: _name,
        setName: function (name) {
            _name = name;
        }
    }
})();
human.setName('somebody');
alert(human.name); // shows an empty string
human = (function () {
    var _name = '';
    return {
        name: function() {
            return _name;
        },
        setName: function (name) {
            _name = name;
        }
    }
})();
human.setName('somebody');
alert(human.name()); // shows 'somebody'
```

Why the second closure works fine, while the first closure is not working? See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NxPFA/).

Please also see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afxVK/), which proves that simple properties can be used instead of getter functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Javascript

- Strings and primitive types (boolean and numeric) are passed by value
- Objects, arrays, and functions are passed by reference

As name is a string `name: _name` will store the current value of `_name` and not the reference to `_name`.

`setName` in your example will modify only `_name`.

`getName` will access `_name` which holds the current value.

`.name` will access the copied value which was set during the initialisation (`name: _name`).

See also [SO: Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please explain more?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
var human = (function () {
    var _name = '';
    var returnObj = {};
    returnObj.name = _name;
    returnObj.setName = function (name) {
        _name = name;
        returnObj.name = name;
    };

    return returnObj;
})();
human.setName('somebody');
alert(human.name);
```

The problem with your code was that `setName` was assigning a value to the `_name` variable and you ware accessing the `name` property of the returned object.