# Property returns empty string, while function works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js

[stack overflow thread similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707532/why-this-javascript-property-returns-empty-string-while-javascript-function-wor)

```
exports.getAddress = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    var lon = req.query.lon;
    var lat = req.query.lat;
    var formattedAddress = "";
    var url1 = 'url'

    request(url1, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {

        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        formattedAddress = body.formattedAddress;
        console.log(formattedAddress); // string address showing
      });

      console.log(formattedAddress); // string is empty
      
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: formattedAddress });
  });
```

I read the above and many posts but can't understand how can i get the string value outside of the function.

Comment: So take the code that needs that data, and move it to where you know the string will be available.

Comment: yeah i did code inside and rename res it worked hav to learn js more.

Comment: Asynchronous programming problems come up in many different languages, and are dealt with differently. For now just get used to the idea that some specific, well-defined functions will require special handling because the end of their execution happens sometime later. This is why there's a callback function in your example. That's just the way of telling the `request` function what you want to do when it eventually finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're accessing `formattedAddress` before `request(...)` completes, welcome to async world :D

To make it work, you should move `res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: formattedAddress });` to inside of request callback, something like this:

```js
exports.getAddress = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    var lon = req.query.lon;
    var lat = req.query.lat;
    var formattedAddress = "";
    var url1 = 'url'

    request(url1, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {

        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        formattedAddress = body.formattedAddress;
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: formattedAddress });
      });
  });
```

Comment: by renaming res working

Comment: Yeap, sorry I didn't see that.